# Angular 6 data binding issue

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am new to angular 6. I have some issues. looking for their solution. please help me.

I have implemented an API. and get data in JSON. I want to show that data in my other component. let me show you the code here.

In App.component.ts
I have written the following code,

```
export class AppComponent {

 name:string;
 year:string;

makeRequest (method, url) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url);
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  } else {
    reject({
      status: this.status,
      statusText: xhr.statusText
    });
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
  reject({
    status: this.status,
    statusText: xhr.statusText
  });
};
xhr.send();
});
}

      Show_movie2(moviename,year)
       {

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" +moviename+"&apikey=123456&y="+year;

        let data=this.makeRequest('GET',script.src)
        .then(function (datums) {
          console.log(datums);

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.error('Augh, there was an error!', err.statusText);
        });

        }

}
```

**and my app.component.html code is like this**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<mat-toolbar-row>
<span>Movie Search</span>
<span class="example-spacer"></span>
<mat-icon class="example-icon">menu</mat-icon>
</mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

 <mat-card style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
 <mat-card-title>
  Search a movie
 </mat-card-title>
 <div class="example-container">
 <mat-form-field>
 <input matInput placeholder="Movie Name" #search>
 </mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Year" value="{{title}}" #year>
 </mat-form-field>

        <div class="example-button-row">

        <button mat-raised-button (click)="Show_movie2(search.value,year.value)" color="accent">Search</button>

      </div>
      </div>

     </mat-card>
     <app-show-movie></app-show-movie>
```

**In app-show-movie the code is like this**

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="120px">
       <mat-grid-tile
       *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
        [colspan]="tile.cols"
        [rowspan]="tile.rows">

        <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>

        <mat-card-title>Movie Name</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTA2NTAyNTMyMDdeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU3MDEyMTY1ODU@._V1_SX300.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">

        <mat-card-actions>
        <mat-icon class="example-icon">favorite_border</mat-icon>

        </mat-card-actions>

        </mat-card>

        </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
```

Now I want to get data from app.component.ts and want to show in app-show-movie. Can anyone of you help me regarding this?

Please ignore the mistakes if any.

Comment: <mat-card-title>Movie Name</mat-card-title> in this.. Movie name will be replaced with the movie name which i got from api in app.component.ts

Comment: Is that your _actual_ api-key ?

Comment: yes.. i have got the data. only issue is to bind this with my page. please can you solve this issue

Comment: I removed it. You shouldn't post API-Keys. Just replace them with dummy data. You wouldn't post actual passwords, would you?

Comment: can you solve this problem ?? @Fildor

Comment: I am afraid this is a little bit too broad, to solve it in an answer. It would have to include some kind of tutorial. But I'd advise to read up on "@Input" and "Smart vs dumb components". Also services would be a good fit here.

Comment: The API key can still be seen in the revision history. Please consider it compromised and invalidate it

Comment: thanks @IngoBürk can you please give the solution to problem